# How can I access this variable? this.hero

Tags: angular, typescript, web

So I went through the documentation on the Angular website, and I built the basic "Heroes" app.

I've been trying to access the input variable hero since I have a certain variable I want to output however I'm getting error.

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: this.hero is undefined
```

This call works in any other method, for example a method that is called during button use, however once I try to call it in ngOnInit() it crashes and gives me that error.

Here's my code:

```
this.route.params.switchMap((params: Params) => this.heroService.getHero(+params['id'])).subscribe(hero => this.hero = hero);
console.log(this.hero.background);
```

where **background** is an attribute of the hero.

I don't need specific code - this was just something that wasn't covered in the tutorial and I'd like some direction.

I've spent many hours searching but I always end up unsuccessful - now before I tear all my hears out can someone give me some guidance?

**Got asked for code so here it is**

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params }   from '@angular/router';
import { Location }                 from '@angular/common';

import { HeroService } from './hero.service';
import { Hero } from './hero';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';

let body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
@Component({
  selector: 'hero-detail',
  templateUrl: './hero-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './hero-detail.component.css' ]
})


export class HeroDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() hero: Hero;
  constructor(
  private heroService: HeroService,
  private route: ActivatedRoute,
  private location: Location
  ) { }

  oldBody:string = body.style.backgroundImage;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.params.switchMap((params: Params) => this.heroService.getHero(+params['id'])).subscribe(hero => this.hero = hero);

    console.log(this.hero.background);
  }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        body.style.backgroundImage = this.oldBody;
    }

  goBack(): void {
    this.location.back();
  }

  updateBackground(): void {
    body.style.backgroundImage = "url('"+this.hero.background+ "')";
  }

  save(): void {
    this.heroService.update(this.hero)
    .then(() => this.goBack());
  }
}
```

Comment: Follow your logic step be step and make sure that the "this" key word is in the context that you think it is.

Comment: @Bindrid Right, in my variable declarations I have `@Input() hero: Hero;` so accessing this would be used by the "this" keyword wouldn't it? I mean there's no other way that I know of - if I use regular hero without this keyword it gives me an error asking me to reference the instance.

Comment: Can you provide some more code please?

Comment: @Tamas I'll provide it in the actual post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your console.log is running before the observable subscription has a chance to fire. The 'hero' field will be undefined until the subscription callback is actually run.

You should move the console log into the subscription like this:

```
this.route.params.switchMap((params: Params) =>
  this.heroService.getHero(+params['id'])
).subscribe(hero => {
  this.hero = hero;
  console.log(this.hero.background);
});
```

Comment: Haha wow, that was fast, thanks for the feedback. I guess everybody has to begin somewhere.

To get a better understanding of your changes; what I was doing was strictly defining the variable but the **ngOnInit** didn't actually initialize the variable yet, by creating a block it ensures that the variable is initialized?

Comment: Making it a block (adding curly braces) changes nothing except that it lets you write multiple statements. (As a convention I always use curly braces  in subscribe callbacks, even if it's only one statement. I think it's clearer.)

Anyway, the code in the 'subscribe' function is run asynchronously (after getHero() completes). But code outside of the subscribe callback, where you had the console.log before, is run synchronously.

Answer (score 0):

Are you actually providing a Hero as an `Input()` when you use the component?? If not, your code should just read:

```
export class HeroDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  public hero: Hero
 // rest of your code
```

Comment: I was for the example, but I stopped using it when I started working on my mini-app. I tried changing it to public before and it still didn't work. :\

Comment: What happens when you come up with a very simple/basic component?Something like export class TestComponent implements OnInit { public message; ngOnInit() this.message = 'hello'; } This should just work.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are defining `hero` as `Input` of your component, and you can set to it directly from your parentComponent like below:

```
<hero-detail [hero]="selectedHero"></hero-detail>  // here selectedHero is what you selected from ParenComponent
```

and according to the error(`this.hero is undefined`) you are facing, you didn't do the above thing, so the `@Input() hero` is still undefined until you got data back from `this.heroService.getHero`.

So simply you have to move the `console.log` to the `subscribe` of `this.heroService.getHero` because it's a asynchronous call.